# Which frameworks / libraries should I take a look at when I want to play an audio livestream on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, stream

For example, if I wanted to play back an shoutcast web radio audio stream on the iPhone, what libs could I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks the best method should be to use [audiostreamer](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer).

Hope this framework helps you.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Umm I haven't tried all but basic formats supported by iPhone